# How to access java based restful service through ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery. I cannot access java based web services by making ajax call.

My code for ajax call is something like this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:"json",
        headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          alert('Success');
        },  
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert('Failure');
        }
});
```

I am getting error :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "server url. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Web service response while accessing  via rest client on browser is something lie this :
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 03 Sep 2014 09:42:32 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunke
"
Any help is greatly appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `url`. Is it something outside of your hosted server?

Comment: The header must be sent serverside

Comment: either your REST server should be on the same domain, or it should include a response header parameter for CORS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 0):

You trying to access different domain data.

So replace with   `dataType:"jsonp" instead of`dataType:"json",

Answer (score 0):

the Header

```
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

must be delivered by the server

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: i´m sure this is the answer and no critisism or a request for clarification